# How to use id and /route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 routes:

```
/route/{id}
/route/add
```

First one shows something based on id provided and second one provies form for adding news item. My problem is that when I hit `/route/add` it takes the add word and treats it as id for the first route.
Is there any solution for this in laravel or do I have to use different route names?

Comment: Try using `->where('id', '[0-9]+');` on the route. That should tell Laravel to generate a regex that only matches numbers.

Comment: Just place the add rule line **before** the another one and/or make your id match only numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes work on a first-come first-served basis. The earlier routes are looked at first. Since you have a wildcard `{id}` on your first of those two routes, Laravel is treating `add` as `{id}` and will be passing off to that controller/closure.

You should switch the two routes around like this:

```
Route::get('route/add', 'Controller@method');
Route::get('route/{id}', 'Controller@method');
```

OR you can always add a filter to the first route in order to tell Laravel that `{id}` should be a number:

```
Route::get('route/{id}', 'Controller@method')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('route/add', 'Controller@method');
```

This way, Laravel will try to match `add` to your `{id}` wildcard but it will fail because `add` is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the two lines:

```
/route/add
/route/{id}
```

The `{id}` parameter is not always expecting a numeric value. A string is also valid like "add".